# Per project documentroot

Tags: apache, xampp

I have had a local server for a couple of months now and every time I start a new project I need to use the server's root directory instead of the root directory of the project.

On my server I have:

```
htdocs
-- project1
---- images
---- js
---- css
-- project2
// etc. //
```

When I go to rawox.co.cc (which is my dev server at home), it will redirect to the portfolio folder (rawox.co.cc/portfolio/) Another project is menology (rawox.co.cc/menology/). In my css for these projects I have to use `background-image: url(../images/logo.png;`. When I upload a project to a public server the css stops working because of those `../`.

My personal thought is that it is caused by the fact that `http://rawox.co.cc/` is set as the DocumentRoot in my apache settings. How would I go around fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual hosts in your httpd.conf.

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.example.com
    ServerName host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/host.example.com-error_log
    TransferLog logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Make for each project a separate project1-vhost.conf file and include it with

```
include project1-vhost.conf
```

in your httpd.conf file. so you can easily activate and deactivate each project

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost

//edit

```
Alias /project1 /path/to/project
<Location /path/to/project>
    Order Allow, Deny
    Allow from All
    ...
</Location>
```

Comment: I know about this but I don't want to use Servername host.example.com, I want Servername example.com/host.

Comment: Then you can try  
    Alias /project1 /path/to/project1
    <Location /path/to/project1>
        Order Allow, Deny
        ...
    </Location